# Edit css:after with jQuery .siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to edit :after element created by css with jQuery.

```
<div class="box">
            <h3 class="social">Social</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"
                  onmouseout="bgc('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)')"
                  onmouseover="bgc('rgba(230, 33, 23, 0.88)')">Youtube</a></li></ul></div>

.box ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.box ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 90%;
}
/* jQuery */
$("document").ready(function bgc(color){
  $('.box ul li a').siblings().css({"border-color": color});
});
```

But this code doesn't work. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: this question has answer already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `after` or `before` elements with JavaScript, but you can change their style by appending classes to their parent element.

```
.colorBlue:after {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

and then:

```
$('.box ul li a').toggleClass('colorBlue');
```

would change border color of `after` element.

Answer (score 0):

> You can not select pseudo elements in jQuery because pseudo-elements
>   themselves are not part of the DOM. - [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Although they are rendered by browsers through CSS as if they were like other real DOM elements, , and thus you can't select and manipulate them directly with jQuery (or *any* JavaScript APIs for that matter, not even the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api)).

See this question for more: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)